# libsvm model file don't save parameters C?

Tags: libsvm

```
  - svm_type epsilon_svr
  - kernel_type rbf
  - gamma 0.0
  - nr_class 2
  - total_sv 6
  - rho -7.92
  - probA 5.32875
  - SV
```

That's my model file,I adjustment parameters C,but don't say it in model file,so where is my adjustment parameters C?

Answer (score 1):

I just found the same error and also posted on libsvm [official issues](https://github.com/cjlin1/libsvm/issues/116) on git repos. ***The C parameters is not saved to the disk*** but when calculating the model ***during cross validation*** and grid search on C and gamma ***is taken into account***, so basically your model and the corresponding support vector are computed using C.
I do not know how to calculate given a set of support vectors it's corresponding C.

Comment: I have an other question, my train set have twenty thousand and I only have one feature,It ran for two hours and the result did not look accurate，why it's to slow?

Comment: Please if you find my answer useful accept it and then open another question for your additional request.